# How to stop the Runnable of Timer gracefully in Android?

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler

I have created a ***runnable*** thread to change/swipe the View Pager position through auto-looping in homepage.

In my app, I want to stop this thread when logout button is clicked.

I have tried ***removecallback*** method but still the app crashes sometimes.

Any other solution?

**Below is my Code:**

```
final Handler offers1Handler = new Handler();

Runnable offers1Runnable;

private void setLooping() {

    offers1Runnable = () -> scrollPager(binding.contentHome.offers1ViewPager);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                offers1Handler.postDelayed(offers1Runnable, 1000);

            }
       },500, 3000);

   }

}


private void onLogout(){
    offers1Handler.removeCallbacks(offers1Runnable);
}
```

Comment: share you code and logcat message to find out your bug.

Comment: Don't you need to set your `timer` variable as a class member?  Then you invoke `cancel` on it in onLogout.

Comment: @selbie I changed timer variable as class member. And cancelled the timer in the logout method as well. But the report says, the error is due to problematic pager adapter.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cancel the timer by yourself, you can use `cancel` method.

the Runnable is not a thread, it just has a method run. the `Timer` is A facility for threads, which to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. if you want to cancel, you actually want to cancel the `Timer`. As the document describes:

> If a caller wants to terminate a timer's task execution thread rapidly, the caller should invoke the timer's cancel method.

if you call the `cancel` method. its execution thread terminates gracefully, and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.